# How to read a text file in Java Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, text

I am a very novice programmer trying to read a text file in Java Eclipse.

> Here is my code:

```
 package readFromfile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class justDo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + 
 "/src/report.txt");


      Scanner hemp = new Scanner(file);
      System.out.println(hemp);



  }
}
```

> Instead of reading a text file and displaying the file's contents in the console I get this:

```
C:\Users\Vanessa\eclipse-workspace\readFromfile
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match 
valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group 
separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q- 
\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\QNaN\E][infinity 
string=\Q?\E]
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting this and explain how to properly read a text file in Java Eclipse? Please help. Thank you all so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the `Scanner` object, not the `File` read.
To do that you have to run over the `Scanner` content, here is an example:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/report.txt");
        Scanner hemp = new Scanner(file);
        while (hemp.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(hemp.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to read more about the `Scanner` functions you can see the API docs:

- [`Scanner.hasNextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--)
- [`Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--)

Comment: Thanks man! This helped out alot. Really apreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java's BufferedReader. Just search up BufferedReader java example and look at the BufferedReader api. It'll let you read files and the tutorial/example will let you know how to print out aspects of the file.